# Grid children swapping places when using grid-row-end

Tags: css, css-grid

I am developing a grid layout for a list of cards. The expected result for the grid is displayed in this image:

[image: Grid - Expected Result]

I am expecting cards #1-6 to be displayed from left to right and top to bottom. In the case where there are more than 6 cards, every subsequent batch of 6 cards *(#7-12, #13-18, ...)* will follow the same grid layout pattern as shown in the image above and will be displayed below the previous batch.

However, in the code snippet posted at the bottom of this question, cards #5 and #6 swap columns when the viewport width is `1200px` or greater. At this breakpoint, card #5 is displayed in column #3 and card #6 is displayed in column #2. I am using `grid-row-end` for my grid children to achieve the masonry look, which I believe is the problem:

```css
.thumbnail:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    grid-row-end: span 5;
}

.thumbnail:nth-child(2n) {
    grid-row-end: span 6;
}
```

I do not want to manually set every 5th and 6th child to swap columns as the number of cards rendered will be dynamic:

```
// I do not want to declare these styles.
.thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
    grid-column: 2;
}

.thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
    grid-row: 6 / 12;
    grid-column: 3;
}
```

**Questions**

- Why are card #5 and #6 swapping columns?
- Are there any changes I can make to my code to get the desired result?

```js
const thumbnails = [
    { category: "Card 1", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 2", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 3", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 4", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 5", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 6", title: "Some title" }
];

const Thumbnail = ({ category, title }) => (
    <li className="thumbnail">
        <div className="thumbnail__image-container"></div>
        <div className="thumbnail__metadata-container">
            <p>{category}</p>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
    </li>
);

const Gallery = () => (
    <ul className="gallery">
        {thumbnails.map((thumbnail, i) => {
            return <Thumbnail key={thumbnail.category} {...thumbnail} />;
        })}
    </ul>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Gallery />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 14px;
    padding: 16px;
    list-style: none;
}

.thumbnail {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.thumbnail__image-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    flex: 1;
    background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 125% auto;
}

.thumbnail__metadata-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .gallery {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .gallery {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: 60px;
        height: auto;
    }

    .thumbnail:nth-child(2n + 1) {
        grid-row-end: span 5;
    }

    .thumbnail:nth-child(2n) {
        grid-row-end: span 6;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the column of the element #5 explicitly and add `grid-auto-flow: dense;` to the grid to make sure the element #6 will be correctly placed. This will also work with any number of element since your pattern is the same and repeating each 6 elements:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .thumbnail:nth-child(6n + 5) {
        grid-column: 2;
    }
}
```

Full code:

```js
const thumbnails = [
    { category: "Card 1", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 2", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 3", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 4", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 5", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 6", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 7", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 8", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 9", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 10", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 11", title: "Some title" },
    { category: "Card 12", title: "Some title" }
];

const Thumbnail = ({ category, title }) => (
    <li className="thumbnail">
        <div className="thumbnail__image-container"></div>
        <div className="thumbnail__metadata-container">
            <p>{category}</p>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
    </li>
);

const Gallery = () => (
    <ul className="gallery">
        {thumbnails.map((thumbnail, i) => {
            return <Thumbnail key={thumbnail.category} {...thumbnail} />;
        })}
    </ul>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Gallery />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow:dense;
    grid-gap: 14px;
    padding: 16px;
    list-style: none;
}

.thumbnail {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.thumbnail__image-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    flex: 1;
    background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 125% auto;
}

.thumbnail__metadata-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .gallery {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .gallery {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: 60px;
        height: auto;
    }

    .thumbnail:nth-child(2n + 1) {
        grid-row-end: span 5;
    }

    .thumbnail:nth-child(2n) {
        grid-row-end: span 6;
    }
    .thumbnail:nth-child(6n + 5) {
        grid-column: 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```